# Qt / C++: Is there a way to automatically register meta types?

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qmetatype

In order to get all of the functionality of Qt's meta type system, I have to call `qRegisterMetaType` at runtime during the initialization of my application. Specifically, I need to register:

- the pointer type for each of my `QObject`-derived classes, i.e. `qRegisterMetaType<MyClass *>()`, and
- each type that I've declared as a meta type using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`.

Currently I do this with a function that just calls `qRegisterMetaType` for each one of these that I manually maintain and update as needed.

This, however, is rather inconvenient and error prone for me. I am often forgetful, and forgetting to register a metatype won't produce any compile errors, but it will cause runtime errors when my code tries to use the metatype system and fails because I forgot to register one of these. Sometimes the error can be difficult to track down.

So is there any way I can have all of my `QObject`-derived classes and declared metatypes get registered automatically?

Some things that might factor into a solution:

- All of my QObject-derived classes I need registered are also derived from my own single base class, so I can use that to implement functionality that every other class will inherit.
- I'm open to using arcane percompiler techinques if necessary!

Comment: It's the same as with not connected signals/slots. You will get a warning when qRegisterMetaType is not declared, but required. Before you ship the application you will want to check your logs/debug outputs. I don't think there is any great way to do this automatically.

Comment: In debug builds I filter the Qt messages and put a breakpoint on warnings. That way if Qt has a warning I know.

Comment: check if this helps [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE for template class](https://forum.qt.io/topic/34226/q_declare_metatype-for-template-class)

Comment: It's a bit tricky thing. You need to create your own factory that will register functors that will call `qRegisterMetaType` in runtime. And this should be used for each exe/dll instance. It can be done with some global container, but because in C++ order of initializing variables is not defined - it may be not trivial. Possible, I'll provide you an example soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't figure out a way to automatically **declare** a meta type, i.e. without providing the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro in the class header, but one could provide a macro where registration is automatically performed (more or less along with meta type declaration). This example is meant to declare and 
register only the pointer type of a given class:

```
#include <QMetaType>

#define METAID(CLASS)                \
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CLASS*)       \
    static struct CLASS##Metaid      \
    {                                \
      CLASS##Metaid()                \
      {                              \
        qRegisterMetaType<CLASS*>(); \
      }                              \
    } _CLASS##metaid;
```

The macro above can be used instead of `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
};

METAID(MyClass)
```

Comment: There is no reason to register OObject-based classes as metatypes. It may be useful only for pointers.

Comment: Another issue: copy ctor is private in QObject - so making ctor in child classes has no sense.

Comment: Yes @DmitrySazonov, but the OP says they have to register QObject-derived classes ... or I misunderstood?

Comment: It is a good question to OP. Only one case that I can imagine - is to save a pointer to QObject-based instance into `QVariant`. As I understood - OP needs to automatically call `qRegisterMetaType` for each usage of `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`.

Comment: This is very wrong if CLASS is a non-copyable type. I'm not sure if it even compiles, or if not - if it links. If it does, it's a runtime error waiting to happen. I'm also not sure if it is valid to invoke `qRegisterMetaType` before `QCoreApplication` gets instantiated. That would at least need to be checked. Finally, `CLASSMetaid` instances will be created in every translation unit that includes that header - they are `static` after all. That's a bit wasteful.

Comment: @KubaOber Non copyable classes won't compile, `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` will fail as usual. It seems meta types declaration and registration succeed even without a `QCoreApplication` instance. Finally, yes: there will be a one-byte sized instance of `CLASSMetaid` for each compilation unit including the `CLASS` header.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o I'm only looking to register the pointer type of all of my classes. The other folks in this thread are correct about not registering the non-pointer class type.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o I hadn't considered using a static struct to do this and I think that's a workable solution for me. Before I accept it though, you should make a few changes: a) change it so that it's not registering the non-pointer class type, b) change instances of `CLASSMetaid` to `CLASS ## Metaid` so that tokens get concatenated correctly, and c) change it to use `qRegisterMetaType()` instead of `qMetaTypeId<T>()` since even though it's currently equivalent, that isn't guaranteed to work in future versions of Qt -- better to use the API function explicitly meant for registering meta types.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o and what about classes with namespaces? That was a my problem some time ago.